# Line break after displaying all the photos of each album

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, flickr

I'm getting images from Flickr using it's API. I'm displaying album name followed by it's corresponding pics and then the next album. Everything is going well but there needs to be a Linebreak after displaying all the photos of each album so that the name of next album will be displayed in next line. But currently name of the next album is being displayed right after the last photo of previous album. I've tried inserting div.append('break tag') in various places but none solved the issue. Please help.
I've attached an image of how the page is looking now.

```html
<html>
<body height="200" width="345">
<h2><div class="img-container" id="flickr"></div></h2>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getList&api_key=d4484e060a112d188a27a51ea64f427e&user_id=13796773%40N04&format=json&nojsoncallback=1",
  "method": "GET",
}
const flickr = $("#flickr");  // the wrapping div, where all albums divs will be appended
$.ajax(settings).done(function(data) {
  $.each(data.photosets.photoset, function(i, gp) {
    const div = $("<div/>");  // a div for each album
    flickr.append(div);
    const albumname = $("<h2/>");  // headline for the album
    albumname.text(gp.title._content + " Gallery");
    div.append(albumname);
    var id = gp.id; 
    var settings1 = {
      "async": true, 
      "crossDomain": true,
      "url": "https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key=d4484e060a112d188a27a51ea64f427e&photoset_id=" + id + "&user_id=13796773%40N04&format=json&nojsoncallback=1",
      "method": "GET",
    }
    $.ajax(settings1).done(function(data) {
      $.each(data.photoset.photo, function(i, gpr) {
        var farmId = gpr.farm;
        var serverId = gpr.server; 
        var id = gpr.id;
        var secret = gpr.secret;
        div.append('<center><a href="https://farm' + farmId + '.staticflickr.com/' + serverId + '/' + id + '_' + secret + '.jpg" target="_blank"><img style="border:1px solid #000000"  src="https://farm' + farmId + '.staticflickr.com/' + serverId + '/' + id + '_' + secret + '.jpg"/></a></center>');  // append images to album div
      }); 
    });
  });
});   
</script> 
</body>
</html>
<style>
img {max-height:125px; margin:3px; float: left; border:1px solid #dedede;} 
</style>
```

[Here is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jm7Xx.jpg)

Comment: The _structure_ is okay already, you have each album contained in a grouping `div` container. The problem is that the images a _floated_, so you need to clear the floating properly, so that the next div does not slide “next to” the images. https://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/

Comment: Isnt it applying only to img elements?

Comment: Is there anyway that I can get images side by side but not the next album name?

Comment: _“Isnt it applying only to img elements?”_ - the float _property_ applies to the images, but it _affects_ more than only them. _“Is there anyway that I can get images side by side but not the next album name?”_ - yes, like I said: _Clear_ the floating.

Comment: Check https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/, if you have troubles understanding how float actually works.

Comment: Clear : both; has done the job. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

Use Style **display:block**

```
its Displays an element as a block element (like <p>). It starts on a new line, and takes up the whole width
```

> img {max-height:125px; margin:3px; display:block float: left;
> border:1px solid #dedede;}

its Work

```html
<html>
<body height="200" width="345">
<h2><div class="img-container" id="flickr"></div></h2>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getList&api_key=d4484e060a112d188a27a51ea64f427e&user_id=13796773%40N04&format=json&nojsoncallback=1",
  "method": "GET",
}
const flickr = $("#flickr");  // the wrapping div, where all albums divs will be appended
$.ajax(settings).done(function(data) {
  $.each(data.photosets.photoset, function(i, gp) {
    const div = $("<div/>");  // a div for each album
    flickr.append(div);
    const albumname = $("<h2/>");  // headline for the album
    albumname.text(gp.title._content + " Gallery");
    div.append(albumname);
    var id = gp.id; 
    var settings1 = {
      "async": true, 
      "crossDomain": true,
      "url": "https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key=d4484e060a112d188a27a51ea64f427e&photoset_id=" + id + "&user_id=13796773%40N04&format=json&nojsoncallback=1",
      "method": "GET",
    }
    $.ajax(settings1).done(function(data) {
      $.each(data.photoset.photo, function(i, gpr) {
        var farmId = gpr.farm;
        var serverId = gpr.server; 
        var id = gpr.id;
        var secret = gpr.secret;
        div.append('<center><a href="https://farm' + farmId + '.staticflickr.com/' + serverId + '/' + id + '_' + secret + '.jpg" target="_blank"><img style="border:1px solid #000000"  src="https://farm' + farmId + '.staticflickr.com/' + serverId + '/' + id + '_' + secret + '.jpg"/></a></center>');  // append images to album div
      }); 
    });
  });
});   
</script> 
</body>
</html>
<style>
img {max-height:125px; margin:3px; display:block float: left; border:1px solid #dedede;} 
</style>
```